# Can we have a grid inside Telerik Modal Window?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-window

I am using ASP.NET MVC architecture.I have a telerik window on a button click, which works fine.The code is as follows-

```
    <% Html.Telerik().Window()
           .Name("Search")
           .Visible(false)
           .Title("Select Users")
           .Content(() => {%>                                           
    <% using (Html.BeginForm("GetUsers", "Administration", FormMethod.Post, 
        new{id ="users-form"}))
    {%>

    <p class="note">Mention the Users name to display information</p>                                                 
    <label for="username">Name:</label>                                                        
    <%= Html.TextBox("username") %>                           
    <div class="form-actions">
    <button type="button" class="bUsername">Search</button>
    </div>  
    <% } %>                                           
    <%})
    .Width(400)                                            
    .Modal(true)                                            
    .Render();%>
```

But when I try to add the telerik grid inside the content of telerik window it gives me error..code follows

```
    <%= Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.OrderID).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(o => o.ContactName).Width(200);
        columns.Bound(o => o.ShipAddress);
        columns.Bound(o => o.OrderDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Width(120);
    })
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => 
    {
        dataBinding.Server().Select("FirstLook", "Grid", new { ajax =
            ViewData["ajax"] });
        dataBinding.Ajax().Select("_FirstLook",
            "Grid").Enabled((bool)ViewData["ajax"]);
    })
    .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Enabled((bool)ViewData["scrolling"]))
    .Sortable(sorting => sorting.Enabled((bool)ViewData["sorting"]))
    .Pageable(paging => paging.Enabled((bool)ViewData["paging"]))
    .Filterable(filtering => filtering.Enabled((bool)ViewData["filtering"]))
    .Groupable(grouping => grouping.Enabled((bool)ViewData["grouping"]))
    .Footer((bool)ViewData["showFooter"])
     %>
```

Error : .Content(() => {%> ----Delegate System.Func does not take 0 arguments.

So want to ask can we have grid inside modal window, if yes then how to implement it and if we cant than whats the alternative to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have any issues displaying a Grid in a Window. The following code, which uses the Customer entity from the Northwind database, worked just fine for me:

```
        <% Html.Telerik().Window()
       .Name("TelerikWindow")
       .Title("Grid in Window")
       .Draggable(true)
       .Modal(true)
       .Content(() =>
       { %>
    <%= Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
            .Name("TelerikGrid")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(c => c.CustomerID);
                columns.Bound(c => c.CompanyName);
                columns.Bound(c => c.ContactName);
                columns.Bound(c => c.Address);
                columns.Bound(c => c.City);
            })
            .Pageable(pageSettings => pageSettings.Enabled(true).PageSize(10))
    %>
    <%})
       .Render();
    %>
```

I would double-check your code to ensure that you are setting the content of the Window correctly, as that seems to be where the issue is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

You can define Grid inside Window by using delegate method or direct output:

MVC 2:

```
<% Html.Telerik().Window()
    ...
    .Content(() =>
    {%>
        <%= Html.Telerik().Grid(***)
            ...
        %>
    <%})
    .Render();
%>
```

MVC 3 Razor:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Window()
    ...
    .Content(
        @<text>
            @(Html.Telerik().Grid<***>()
                ...
            )
        </text>
    )
)
```

**See Also:**

[Grid inside Window - Forum](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/window/grid-on-window-not-working.aspx)

[Using with the Razor View Engine - Help](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/using-with-the-razor-view-engine.html)